# Flickr API. Get photo,tags, exif info from Flickr's explore page

Tags: python, flickr

I am working on a personal project. I was wondering if Flickr's API gives access to [Explore page](http://www.flickr.com/explore/)?

I will be using python.

Comment: And you're not reading https://www.flickr.com/services/api/ because...?

Comment: I did and I dont see a method to access explore page.

Comment: Explore is called interestingness in the docs. https://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.interestingness.getList.html Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explore is called interestingness in the docs.

https://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.interestingness.getList.html

Thanks